# Scan Quantum mechanics: Status of current research

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, superposition

I recently stumbled on a new interpretation of Quantum mechanics, called Scan Quantum Mechanics, given by Beatriz Gato-Rivera. She suggests a quantity called quantum inertia, which divides the classical and quantum regimes of a system. It also helps in reinterpreting superposition from a different perspective.

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03093) on arXiv gives a detailed account of the scan quantum mechanics and also suggests some experiments to test some of it's results!

Although a google search doesn't seem like this theory has got much attention in the scientific community, I am just curious about any probable follow-ups either experimentally or theoretically on these lines.

Comment: This theory is not an interpretation of quantum mechanics at all. Rather, it is an alternative theory with different implications, like the spontaneous collapse theory https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6314